# Работа кастомного компаратора в алгоритмах lower_bound и upper_bound

Tags: c++, алгоритм, лямбда-выражение

Задача следующая: написать функцию, которая получала бы итераторы на начало и конец   отсортированного vector и символ prefix, выдавала бы начало и конец диапазона, строки в котором начинаются с prefix.
Застрял на написании лямбды, которую можно подставить в алгоритм поиска. Все ошибки на этапе компиляции, соответственно, не могу пошагово пройтись, и понять, где же именно моя ошибка. По всей видимости, я не до конца (или даже совсем) не поимаю, как работает кастомный компаратор.
Код одной из реализаций (тоже с ошибкой):

```
template <typename RandomIt>
pair<RandomIt, RandomIt> FindStartsWith(RandomIt range_begin, RandomIt range_end, 
char prefix) {
        auto start = upper_bound(range_begin, range_end, prefix, 
                    [](const string a, char prefix) {char b = static_cast<char> (prefix + 1);  
                    return a[0] < b; });
        auto finish = lower_bound(range_begin, range_end, prefix,  
                    [](const string a, char prefix) {return a[0] < prefix; });
        return make_pair(start, finish);
```

Ошибка сообщает о том, что в лямбде невозможно преобразовать аргумент 1 из "const Ту" в "const std::string".

И что со всем этим делать?

Comment: Забудьте о С++, займитесь чем-то ближе к людям

Answer (score 0, accepted):

STL алгоритмы (да и любые сторонние библиотеки) содержат правила, которым должны соответствовать самописные компараторы или функторы.

---

Идем на любой источник документации по С++ и ищем ограничения для компаратора `std::upper_bound`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Аналогично для `std::lower_bound`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Из этого делаем вывод:

1. компаратор для upper_bound должен первым аргументом должен принимать значение value, а вторым аргумент - значение, полученное из итератора
2. компаратор для lower_bound должен первым аргументом должен принимать значение, полученное из итератора, а вторым аргумент - значение value

---

`std::lower_bound` вернет вам итератор на начало множества, определенного условием в компараторе, итератор, возвращаемый `std::upper_bound` итератор будет как минимум **не меньше** этого итератора. Проще говоря, поиск в `std::uppe_bound` стоит осуществлять в диапазоне `(std::lower_bound(begin, end), end)`

---

Сравнение char переменных через `<` ничем хорошим не закончится - вместо определенного символа вы получите целое множество символов определяемое компаратором. Вместо этого лучше сравнивать префикс строки и заданный префикс через `!=`.

---

Учитывая вышесказанное:

```
template <typename RandomIt>
pair<RandomIt, RandomIt> FindStartsWith(const RandomIt range_begin, const RandomIt range_end, char prefix) {
    auto start = 
        lower_bound(
            range_begin, 
            range_end,
            prefix,         
            [](const string& a, char value) {
                return a[0] != value; 
            }
        );

    auto finish = 
        upper_bound(
            start,
            range_end,
            prefix,
            [](char value, const string& a) {
                return a[0] != value; 
            }
        );

    return make_pair(start, finish);
}
```

Comment: >Сравнение char переменных через < ничем хорошим не закончится - вместо определенного символа вы получите целое множество символов определяемое компаратором. Вместо этого лучше сравнивать префикс строки и заданный префикс через !=.  Где можно про это почитать более подробно? Я думал чары сравниваются как и инты...

Comment: @ArMANIAK в том то и дело, что чары сравниваются, как и инты. Но зачем так делать? Если вам нужен определенный префикс - сравнивайте с определенным префиксом, если вам нужно множество префиксов - используйте `<` и другие операторы. С помощью `<` можно получить множество из одного символа, но, опять же, зачем, если придумали `==` и `!=`? :)

Comment: Не знаю, почему, но код с == и != отрабатывает не так, как нужно и выдает итераторы не на те места в массиве.  При проверке массива строк, в которой нет строк на заданную букву, он выдает итераторы на конец массива, а не на то место, где можно было бы вставить новую строку на заданную букву, не нарушая отсортированности...

Comment: @ArMANIAK, вам стоило изначально указать, что вы собираетесь так делать, в таком случае действительно нужно использовать `<`.

Comment: Спасибо, что помогли разобраться. По крайней мере, я теперь лучше стал понимать эти два алгоритма. Осталось со второй частью задачи разобраться, но это уже совсем другой разговор =) Еще раз - спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Еще один простой (поиск в векторе целых чисел (куда уж проще)) пример, показывающий работу с [lower_bound](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/lower_bound/) и [upper_bownd](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/upper_bound/).

Обратите внимание, что алгоритм `upper_bound/lower_bound` устроен так, что для сравнения передаваемого в эти функции ключа (`const T& val` в описании функций в вышеприведенных ссылках) с элементами массива может  использоваться один и тот же компаратор
(`static bool cmp (int a, int b) { ... }` в примере).

Если  в компараторе вы предполагаете сравнивать элемент массива с внешней переменной, которая доступна компаратору (например, лямбда функция в примере), то *важно знать*, что `lower_bound` передает элемент массива в компаратор в первом аргументе, а `upper_bound` во втором и *результат сравнения должен меняться на обратный !*
(см `return` в лямбдах в примере).

Возможно имеет смысл напомнить, что при успешном поиске `lower_bound` возвращает позицию первого из нескольких одинаковых элементов, а `upper_bound` возвращает позицию сразу за последним (или можно считать, что позицию в которую можно вставить новый элемент, равный искомому и при этом упорядоченность массива сохранится). При неуспешном поиске обе функции возвращают одну и ту же позицию, ту в которую можно вставить искомый элемент.

```
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ cat tublb.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>    // std::lower_bound, std::upper_bound, std::sort
#include <vector>       // std::vector

using namespace std;

bool cmp (int a, int b) {
  return a < b;
}

int main (int ac, char *av[]) {
  cout << __FILE__ << '\n';

  int myints[] = {12,20,30,30,22,15,10,20,40,50};
  std::vector<int> v(myints, myints + sizeof(myints)/sizeof(int)); // 12 20 30 30 22 15 10 20 40 50

  std::sort (v.begin(), v.end());                // 10 12 15 20 20 22 30 30 40 50
  std::vector<int>::iterator low,up;
  low=std::lower_bound (v.begin(), v.end(), 20); //          ^
  up= std::upper_bound (v.begin(), v.end(), 20); //                ^

  cout << "sorted array\nposition:  ";
  for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
    cout << i << "  ";
  cout << "\nvalue:     ";
  for (auto n : v)
    cout << n << ' ';
  cout << '\n';

  cout << "lookup 20 (more than one number in the array)\n";
  std::cout << "lower_bound at position " << (low- v.begin()) << '\n';
  std::cout << "upper_bound at position " << (up - v.begin()) << '\n';

  low=std::lower_bound (v.begin(), v.end(), 25);
  up= std::upper_bound (v.begin(), v.end(), 25);
  cout << "lookup 25 (number not present in the array)\n";
  std::cout << "lower_bound at position " << (low- v.begin()) << '\n';
  std::cout << "upper_bound at position " << (up - v.begin()) << '\n';

  low=std::lower_bound (v.begin(), v.end(), 15, cmp);
  up= std::upper_bound (v.begin(), v.end(), 15, cmp);
  cout << "lookup 15 (one value, using cmp())\n";
  std::cout << "lower_bound at position " << (low- v.begin()) << '\n';
  std::cout << "upper_bound at position " << (up - v.begin()) << '\n';

  int dv = 2;  // search array values by high (second) digit
  low=std::lower_bound (v.begin(), v.end(), 88, // here this value is not realy using
            [dv](int arr_elem, int val) {
              // cout << "LB dv=" << dv << " arr_elem=" << arr_elem << " val=" << val <<  '\n';
              return arr_elem / 10 < dv;
            });
  up= std::upper_bound (v.begin(), v.end(), 188, // here this value is not realy using
            [dv](int val, int arr_elem) {
              // cout << "UB dv=" << dv << " arr_elem=" << arr_elem << " val=" << val <<  '\n';
              return dv < arr_elem / 10;
            });

  cout << "lookup " << dv * 10 << " ... " << (dv + 1) * 10 - 1 <<  " (numbers from the second ten, using lambda[dv = " << dv << "])\n";
  std::cout << "lower_bound at position " << (low- v.begin()) << '\n';
  std::cout << "upper_bound at position " << (up - v.begin()) << '\n';

  return 0;

}
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ 
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ g++ tublb.cpp 
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ ./a.out
tublb.cpp
sorted array
position:  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  
value:     10 12 15 20 20 22 30 30 40 50 
lookup 20 (more than one number in the array)
lower_bound at position 3
upper_bound at position 5
lookup 25 (number not present in the array)
lower_bound at position 6
upper_bound at position 6
lookup 15 (one value, using cmp())
lower_bound at position 2
upper_bound at position 3
lookup 20 ... 29 (numbers from the second ten, using lambda[dv = 2])
lower_bound at position 3
upper_bound at position 6
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$
```

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, кому-то мой пост покажется изобретением велосипеда, возможно, кому-то мой пост поможет вникнуть в тему. Не знаю. Для меня наконец-то свершилось открытие, до которого я шел без малого 3 дня. Я наконец понял логику работы лямбда-выражения или функции-компаратора в алгоритмах lower_bound и upper_bound.
Моя основная проблема была в том, что я верил, что алгоритм сам найдет границу выполнения условия, сравнивая значения. На самом же деле true или false, переданные из сравнения, определяют лишь, куда сместится поиск - в сторону начала или конца отсортированной области.
Так, например, при векторе {1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 6} и внешней переменной,  равной 2, и алгоритме lower_bound при компараторе, сравнивающем элемент_вектора > внешняя_переменная, найти тройку будет невозможно, так как первое значение, принятое на проверку будет 3, как середина интервала, т.к. 3 > 2, интервал поиска станет от 3 до конца вектора. Ну, а так как все числа справа больше 2, то итогом вычисления станет конец вектора. 
Если же сравнивать результат на меньше, то получим итератор, указывающий на двойку, что, в принципе, нас тоже не устраивает, т.к. двойка не меньше двойки, и уж тем более это не будет нижним пределом...
Обобщу вышесказанное, и добавлю несколько моментов по этим алгоритмам:

1. В алгоритме lower_bound для сортированных диапазонов диапазон делится на две части, и при возврате true из компаратора поиск смещается в правую область. У алгоритма upper_bound - в левую.
2. При использовании кастомного компаратора или лямбда-выражения в этих алгоритмах алгоритм сам передает переменную для сравнения и объект сравнения в функцию, т.е. для лямбды захват внешней переменной не актуален, он просто записывается в круглых скобках вместе с объектом. lower_bound принимает (объект_сравнения, переменная_сравнения). upper_bound принимает переменные в обратном порядке: (переменная_сравнения, объект_сравнения). То же самое мы записываем в качестве аргументов для функции-компаратора. За эту часть открытия особая благодарность @RiotBr3aker

Как-то так, бугафф много, надеюсь, кому-то поможет.

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Если у вас исходный диапазон отсортирован по возрастанию (то есть предикатом "меньше"), то в качестве компаратора и для `lower_bound`, и для `upper_bound` вы можете использовать только предикат "меньше" (возможно более "расслабленный").  Вопрос только в том, какой из двух параметров этого предиката будет элементом последовательности, а какой - искомым ключом. Ответ на этот вопрос дан @RiotBr3aker. Если же ваш компаратор для `lower_bound`/`upper_bound` не согласован с компаратором упорядочения, то поведение не определено и разглядывать работу этих алгоритмов смысла нет.

Comment: В том-то и дело, что приступая к работе, я не знал, что предикат алгоритма поиска должен соответствовать предикату сортировки. В моем понимании дело обстояло так: по средством лямбды я говорю алгоритму "найди мне, мне, где элементы становятся равны (больше/меньше) какому-то значению". И тут же lower_bound и upper_bound  начинают искать первые элементы, соответствующие утверждениям в  их лямбдах. И вот для того, чтоб развеять этот миф, мне понадобилось три дня тыканья в куда-попало